# Need search filters, place # of search items on top of listing and

Tags: feature-request, search

1. Place # of items found on top of the page. I have to scroll to the bottom of the page to find out if my search keywords caused too many or too few result items.
2. There's no clear pattern for search results. Where the keywords found in the title, body,  or both? Which keywords were used? Do the results include all the words or some depending of how many results it found? Some search engines try to use fewer of the keywords to increase number of results. I don't particularly like this feature because I don't know when they are doing it unless they highlight the keywords. SO doesn't do this.
3. Need filters on search criteria, like search for keywords in title only, body only or both. Use all the keywords or some.. etc. Search by tag.

Comment: @Brad was it necessary to bump this to change `-` to `.`?

Answer (score 1):

A few recent changes in search..

1. Search now *HEAVILY* weights title in the results, since people seemed to really like that approach (used on the /ask page, which searched exclusively on title alone).
2. Any individual search terms which map directly to the top 40 tags will be auto-converted to tag searches. So if you enter

   > c++ entities

   it will convert to

   > [c++] entities

   automagically.

Try again and see if it is more to your liking.